# Xcode swift iOS - GameScene does non have a member named

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, skaction

Please can anyone help me relocate some code, I understand the event may need to be moved but I'm not sure where.  I've looked for the answer already but I cant see anything specific to my problem.

The error is

> 'GameScene' does not have a member named 'spawnCrow'

Here is the code (error on line 1)....

```
    var spawn = SKAction.runBlock({() in self.spawnCrow()}) //THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS
    var delay = SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(2.0))
    var spawnThenDelay = SKAction.sequence([spawn, delay])
    var spawnThenDelayForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(spawnThenDelay)
    self.runAction(spawnThenDelayForever)

    self.addChild(crow)

    func spawnCrow() {
```

Please let me know if more code is needed, I'll be happy to share.

UPDATED WITH ENTIRE CODE

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {


var cat = SKSpriteNode()
var crow = SKSpriteNode()
var crowTexture1 = SKTexture()
var skyColor = SKColor()
var moveAndRemoveCrow = SKAction()


override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake( 0.0, -4.0 )

    skyColor = SKColor(red:113.0/255.0, green:197.0/255.0, blue:207.0/255.0, alpha:1.0)
    self.backgroundColor = skyColor

    var catTexture1 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Cat1")
    catTexture1.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.Nearest
    var catTexture2 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Cat2")
    catTexture2.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.Nearest

    var anim = SKAction.animateWithTextures([catTexture1, catTexture2], timePerFrame: 0.2)
    var run = SKAction.repeatActionForever(anim)

    cat = SKSpriteNode(texture: catTexture1)
    cat.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2.2, y: self.frame.size.height / 7.0 )
    cat.runAction(run)

    cat.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: cat.size.height / 2.0)
    cat.physicsBody!.dynamic = true
    cat.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = false

    self.addChild(cat)

    // start of crow test


    var crowTexture1 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "crow")
    crowTexture1.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.Nearest

    crow = SKSpriteNode(texture: crowTexture1)
    crow.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 1.8, y: self.frame.size.height / 1.2 )

    // crow test 2 spawn

    var distanceToMove = CGFloat(self.frame.size.width + 2 * crowTexture1.size().width);
    var moveCrow = SKAction.moveByX(-distanceToMove, y:0, duration:NSTimeInterval(0.01 * distanceToMove));
    var removeCrow = SKAction.removeFromParent();
    moveAndRemoveCrow = SKAction.sequence([moveCrow, removeCrow]);

    var spawn = SKAction.runBlock({() in self.spawnCrow()})
    var delay = SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(2.0))
    var spawnThenDelay = SKAction.sequence([spawn, delay])
    var spawnThenDelayForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(spawnThenDelay)
    self.runAction(spawnThenDelayForever)

    self.addChild(crow)

    // end of crow test

    // crow func start

    func spawnCrow() {

        var crow = SKSpriteNode(texture: crowTexture1)
        crow.position = CGPointMake( self.frame.size.width + crowTexture1.size().width * 2, 0 );
        crow.zPosition = 0; // previous value -10;

        var height = UInt32( self.frame.size.height / 3 )
        var y = arc4random() % height;

        crow.position = CGPointMake(0.0, CGFloat(y))
        crow.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 2.0 )
        crow.physicsBody!.dynamic = false

        crow.addChild(crow)

        crow.runAction(moveAndRemoveCrow)

        crow.addChild(crow)
    }

    // crow func end

    var groundTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Ground")
    groundTexture.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.Nearest

    var moveGroundSprite = SKAction.moveByX(-groundTexture.size().width, y: 0, duration: NSTimeInterval(0.01 * groundTexture.size().width))
    var resetGroundSprite = SKAction.moveByX(groundTexture.size().width, y: 0, duration: 0.0)
    var moveGroundSpritesForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([moveGroundSprite,resetGroundSprite]))

    for var i:CGFloat = 0; i < 2 + self.frame.size.width / ( groundTexture.size().width); ++i {
        var sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: groundTexture)
        sprite.position = CGPointMake(i * sprite.size.width, sprite.size.height / 2)
        sprite.runAction(moveGroundSpritesForever)
        self.addChild(sprite)
    }

    var dummy = SKNode()
    dummy.position = CGPointMake(0, groundTexture.size().height / 2)
    dummy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, groundTexture.size().height))
    dummy.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
    self.addChild(dummy)

        var skylineTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Skyline")
        skylineTexture.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.Nearest

        var moveSkylineSprite = SKAction.moveByX(-skylineTexture.size().width, y: 0, duration: NSTimeInterval(0.1 * skylineTexture.size().width))
        var resetSkylineSprite = SKAction.moveByX(skylineTexture.size().width, y: 0, duration: 0.0)
        var moveSkylineSpritesForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([moveSkylineSprite,resetSkylineSprite]))

        for var i:CGFloat = 0; i < 2 + self.frame.size.width / ( skylineTexture.size().width); ++i {
            var sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: skylineTexture)
            sprite.zPosition = -20;
            sprite.position = CGPointMake(i * sprite.size.width, sprite.size.height / 2 + groundTexture.size().height)
            sprite.runAction(moveSkylineSpritesForever)
            self.addChild(sprite)
    }
}

 override func  touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    cat.physicsBody!.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
    cat.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 15))

}

    func clamp(min: CGFloat, max: CGFloat, value: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        if( value > max ) {
            return max;
        } else if( value < min ) {
            return min;
        } else {
            return value;
        }

    }


  override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */

    cat.zRotation = self.clamp( -1, max: 0.5, value: cat.physicsBody!.velocity.dy * ( cat.physicsBody!.velocity.dy < 0 ? 0.003 : 0.001 ) );
}
```

}

Comment: The compiler warning is pretty straightforward—you apparently don't have a function named `spawnCrow` defined on your `GameScene` class.  It would help to have more code, perhaps the entire class on which this function is defined?

Comment: Probably just a copy/paste mistake, but you're missing a closing `}` on `func spanCrow()` but otherwise I ran this code sample inside an existing `GameScene` I had and had no problem. Could you post the rest of your file?

Comment: @PatrickLynch Thank you for your help, I've included the entire code as requested, thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either move the declaration of `spawnCrow` outside of the current function context:

```
func yourMethod() {
    var spawn = SKAction.runBlock({() in self.spawnCrow()})
}

func spawnCrow() {
    // do some spawning
}
```

or remove the `self` and continue to have the definition inside the function:

```
func yourMethod() {
    func spawnCrow() {

    }

    var spawn = SKAction.runBlock({() in spawnCrow()})
}
```

Note that you can actually remove the `() in` all together in both cases.

Comment: @luk2392 Thank you for your help, I've tried to remove the 'self' but I still have the error, I'm sure its something obvious but it's really bugging me.  I've copied the entire code in the original edit.  Please let me know if you spot something wrong with it.

Comment: @RichTownsend You have to choose option 2. Remove the `self` and move the declaration of the method to somewhere before the first use of the method. Note that you probably should rename some of the `crow` because they will definitely result in a naming conflict.

Comment: @luk2392 thank you, would you be able to show me on GitHub please? I'm moving the line however I still get the error.  Appologies for my messy code too. [Link to my GitHub](https://github.com/rich84ts/Test/blob/master/Test/GameViewController.swift)